# Row difference calculation in dataframe from the first instance for each group

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, dplyr, lapply

Input Data

```
ID   value  
a    10  
a    12  
a    18  
a    13  
b    23  
b    25  
b    33  
c    17  
c    23  
c    27
```

OUTPUT data Should be look like

```
ID   value     Diff  
a    10        0  
a    12        2    
a    18        8  
a    13        3  
b    23        0   
b    25        2  
b    33       10  
c    17        0  
c    23        6  
c    27       10
```

i got this code from net

```
library(data.table)  
DT <- as.data.table(dat)  
DT[, `:=`(DIFTIME, c(0, diff(as.Date(DATETIME)))), by = "ID"]
```

but this only create difference between two successive  row not from the first instance of that group

```
dat<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
DATETIME = structure(c(1328346000,1328479200, 1331024400,1331025400, 1328086800, 1328184000,   1336287600, 1336424400),
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
VALUE = c(300L,150L, 650L, 450L, 855L, 240L, 340L, 240L)),
.Names = c("ID", "DATETIME","VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `dplyr`, where `df` is the original data

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, ID) %>% mutate(Diff = value - first(value))
#    ID value Diff
# 1   a    10    0
# 2   a    12    2
# 3   a    18    8
# 4   a    13    3
# 5   b    23    0
# 6   b    25    2
# 7   b    33   10
# 8   c    17    0
# 9   c    23    6
# 10  c    27   10
```

Answer (score 3):

using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, Diff:=value-value[1], by=ID]
df
 #   ID value Diff
 #1:  a    10    0
 #2:  a    12    2
 #3:  a    18    8
 #4:  a    13    3
 #5:  b    23    0
 #6:  b    25    2
 #7:  b    33   10
 #8:  c    17    0
 #9:  c    23    6
#10:  c    27   10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c"), value = c(10L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 23L, 25L, 33L, 17L, 
23L, 27L)), .Names = c("ID", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in base R using the `ave` function.

```
dat$Diff <- ave( dat$value, dat$ID, FUN = function(x) x - x[1] )
```